# How to set the EQU operator to work properly?

Tags: batch-file

Everything works fine in this program except when user enters the correct number generated by the program. For example, it replies "too low" if you enter 13, and "too high" if you enter 14. How do you fix this so the 3rd if statement functions properly?

```
@echo off
title Game
set num1=%random%%101
:start
set /p num2=Enter a number: 
if %num2% gtr %num1% (echo too high
pause
cls
goto :start
)
if %num2% lss %num1% (echo too low
pause
cls
goto :start
)
if %num2% equ %num1% (echo Bingo!)
pause
cls
exit
```

Comment: I can't replicate your problem; the code you have posted works as intended for me (although I should point out that your code to set num1 should probably read `set /a num1=%random%%%101` if you want to set num1 to a random number between 0 and 100).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This batch file works fine:

```
@echo off
title Game
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /A num1=%random% %% 101
:Retry
cls
set "num2="
set /P "num2=Enter a number (%num1%): "
if !num2! GTR %num1% (
    echo too high
    pause
    goto Retry
)
if !num2! LSS %num1% (
    echo too low
    pause
    goto Retry
)
if !num2! EQU %num1% (
    endlocal
    echo Bingo!
    pause
    exit /B
)
goto Retry
```

The line

```
set num1=%random%%101
```

could be also used in the batch file above, but creates

- a number with a random part and
- appended the first argument passed to the batch file if called with a parameter at all and
- appended the digits `0` and `1`.

I suppose like [SomethingDark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158862/somethingdark) that a random number between 0 and 100 is wanted here.

**start** is a standard Windows command and therefore it is advisable not to use **start** as label although possible.

Delayed expansion is enabled and used for `num2` to avoid an exit of the batch file caused by a syntax error when the batch user enters nothing or by mistake not a number.

Also the environment variable `num2` is always unset before prompting the user as otherwise the batch user could just hit <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to continue with whatever variable `num2` currently has as value.

Note: The random number is output in prompt text to see what to enter for testing.